# Webview does not close after leaving the page in Xamarin.Forms Application

Tags: xamarin, webview, youtube, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have spent many many hours trying to figure out how to stop the webview from being active after I have left the webview page. The reason I discovered this is because Google Play Store rejected the app because the app was breaking the terms and services with youtube. This is because the youtube video keeps playing in the background even when the page has been left. I am using xamarin.forms to create the webview in the .cs file (seen below). The below code is how I am displaying the youtube video channel inside of the app. This currently runs cross platform: ios/android.

### Tried Solutions

I have tried looking into solutions like the onPause() solution below:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mWebView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

However, xamarin webviews do not have access to an OnPause().

I have also looked into

```
Webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

but I am not sure how to incorporate that into the app so that it would execute whenever the app moves off of the webview page.

### Current Code

```
public partial class YoutubePage : ContentPage
{
    public YoutubePage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
                Url = "https://www.youtube.com/",
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                webView
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: use the page's OnDisappearing method

Comment: Long gone, but just wondering, a fast and easy workaround would be to just load another URL just before leaving/closing the webview page?. Something like: webView.Source = "https://www.google.com/";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OnDisappearing` lifecycle event to set your WebView to a blank page:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    webView.Source = "about:page";
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

Use the `OnAppearing` lifecycle event to set your WebView's source back to the original content:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    webView.Source = "https://youtube.com";
}
```

This of course will disrupt the user experience, if you wish to pause/resume the `Android.WebKit.WebView` you can subclass `WebView` and `WebViewRender` to add that feature.

### PausableWebView

#### Interface:

```
public interface IPausableWebViewRenderer
{
    void Pause();
    void Resume();
}
```

#### `Xamarin.Forms` PausableWebView:

```
public class PausableWebView : WebView
{
    public IPausableWebViewRenderer Renderer;

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (renderer != null) renderer.Pause();
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        if (renderer != null) renderer.Resume();
    }
}
```

#### `Xamarin.Android` PausableWebViewRenderer:

```
public class PausableWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer, IPausableWebViewRenderer
{
    Android.Webkit.WebView webView;

    public PausableWebViewRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        webView = Control;
        if (e.OldElement != null)
            (e.OldElement as PausableWebView).Renderer = null;
        if (e.NewElement != null)
            (e.NewElement as PausableWebView).Renderer = this;
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (webView != null) webView.OnPause();
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        if (webView != null) webView.OnResume();
    }
}
```

#### Example:

#### `XAML`:

```
<local:PausableWebView x:Name="webView" Source="https://youtube.com" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

#### `OnDisappearing` / `OnAppearing`:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    webView.Pause();
    base.OnDisappearing();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    webView.Resume();
}
```

Comment: Is there something similar for iOS?